# stop bash try to display every possible result and auto-complete when ambiguous result find

Tags: bash, autocomplete, inputrc

This is my `.inputrc`

```
  9 set show-all-if-unmodified on
 10 set menu-complete-display-prefix on
 11 #set completion-ignore-case on
 12 set disable-completion on
```

1) How do I stop bash try to display every possible result, but just list the results same as I do with `ls`?

Current behavior:

```
[11:56:33dev@srv:~/test/config$ [Tab]
Display all 1643 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Desired behavior:

`[11:39:07]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ls[Tab]
a.ini  config.ini  environment.ini  mappings.csv  market.ini trace.ini`

2) How do I stop my bash auto-complete when ambiguous result find, but only show the list of possible results?

Current behavior:

```
[12:04:50]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ./ma[Tab]
mappings.csv  market.ini
[12:04:50]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ./mappings.csv
```

Desired behavior:

```
[12:04:50]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ./ma[Tab]
mappings.csv  market.ini
[12:04:50]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ./ma
```

Comment: In sub-question 1, your "example behavior" and "desired behavior" _have different inputs_ – the first is trying to complete an empty input, the second has 'ls'. Please clarify.

Comment: When it's trying to auto-complete an empty line, it's trying to complete a *command name*, not a filename, and there are a lot more commands (1643, apparently) than files.